# Statelessness of REST

Tags: rest, web-applications, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture, stateless

I am creating a REST service that has two methods one is **GetAll** and other is **GetById**.In my scenario, database request is very costly so i want to store output of **GetAll** somewhere (Cache) and use it for subsequent request **GetById**.

*One of the characteristic of REST is it should be Statelessness. A request cannot be dependent on a past request and a service treats each request independently.* 
I want to understand what should be ideal approach to handle such scenarios or how to design this requirement in REST?

Comment: Even if you cached the data, your service would still be stateless. It doesn't matter if `GetById` is called before `GetAll`. If `GetById` is called, and there are no data cached, then it will just get the data it needs. The order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement for statelessness in REST is that the service should *appear* to be stateless. It doesn't matter if the service maintains some state internally. That's just an implementation detail.

Comment: That is not true. The definition of stateless implies that one request should never assume work done by a previous request. For example a request should never assume that a previous request handled authentication.

Comment: It amounts to the same thing.

Comment: if a service request is storing something,doesn't it become stateful?could you briefly tell me difference between stateful & stateless services?

Comment: What if it behaves the same whether it has stored something or not? Stateless means it behaves the same no matter the order of calls. IMHO it's allowed to cache some data just as long as the service behavior is the same whether the data are cached or not - it still has to return the same result, it's just allowed to return the same result faster.

Comment: Why use state then and not expose it? That'd be the worst of both worlds. You don't want state because it scales much better.

Comment: @DanMan: scaling isn't always everything

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to achieve what you want is by using caching, like `MemoryCache`.

You create a separate, private function which fetches all the data and caches it in memory. Then you can have both `GetAll` and `GetById` use that function.

Your service will remain **stateless**.

`MemoryCache` usage example

```
MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
string cacheName = "MyCache";

if (!cache.Contains(cacheName) || cache[cacheName] == null)
{
    // get data
    var data = ...

    // cache data
    cache.Set(cacheName, data, new CacheItemPolicy() { SlidingExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).TimeOfDay });
}

return cache[cacheName];
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many solutions to this. one solution I would recommend you is the following:

configure infinispan to use it as a cache mechanism. inside there store a concurrent hashmap with key the query and with value the resultset of your database,

second time you want to getAll, check if the query exists as a key to your cache, if yes retrieve value from cache, else contact database and then insert the result in the cache.